# Wrong size of the encrypted data (AES)

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, cryptostream

I need to perform encryption array of byte []. I used the example available on the Microsoft. Unfortunately, the encrypted data is truncated to the size that is a multiple of 16. If, in the example of the data I will add 8 times byte 0, the data will be encrypted properly.
Padding has been set, but I do not see anything to change it.
How to solve this problem, the data do not become cut off.

```
public byte[] EncryptAES(byte[] plainBytes)
{
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] FKey = encoding.GetBytes("A002AD9AD73C402190C3E733D82CEA00");
    byte[] FIV = encoding.GetBytes("zyxwvutsrqponmlk");

    // Check arguments.
    if (plainBytes == null || plainBytes.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    if (FKey == null || FKey.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (FIV == null || FIV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    byte[] encrypted;
    // Create an RijndaelManaged object
    // with the specified key and IV.
    using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijAlg.Key = FKey;
        rijAlg.IV = FIV;
        rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                // plainBytes.Length = 2216 
                csEncrypt.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

                // encrypted.Length = 2208
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
    return encrypted;
}
```

Comment: Hi Emil, could you share the link where you attained the source code example please?

Comment: @Mr.Mr. It may help you (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CryptoStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx):

> You should always explicitly close your CryptoStream object after you are done using it by calling the [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx) method. Doing so flushes the stream and **causes all remain blocks of data to be processed by the CryptoStream object**. However, if an exception occurs before you call the [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx) method, the CryptoStream object might not be closed. To ensure that the [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx) method always gets called, place your call to the [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx) method within the finally block of a try/catch statement.

(**My emphasis**)

So, call [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx) before you try to do anything with the results.

---

Basically, [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Byte_padding) is used to deal with the last block of a sequence of encrypted blocks. Since the `CryptoStream` doesn't know how many times you intend to call `Write()`, it doesn't apply padding or write any final incomplete block until you call `Close`.

(Or, as Monkieboy points out, [`FlushFinalBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock.aspx) can also be used to indicate that you're finished)

Comment: I thought that this is not required if I use block using {}.
Can you show the code where you need to take advantage of the option Close ()?

Comment: @EmilJ - You need to do it *somewhere* before you do `msEncrypt.ToArray`. It can be either `Close` or `Dispose` (or `using`), they're equivalent in this case

Comment: Thank you. Subject to closing. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I thought the `csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();` just after `csEncrypt.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);` would work?

Comment: @Monkieboy - yes, that would also work. It's strange - I was sure something along those lines was available, but I swear I looked through the methods twice or thrice and couldn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

Just calling FlushFinalBlock() resolves the multiple of 16 problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            csEncrypt.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
        }
        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: After all, exactly as I do, and it does not help. The problem is somewhere in the last block of data (no padding).

Comment: @EmilJ - No, it's *not* exactly as you do - they're waiting until `csEncrypt` has been `Dispose`d (or `Close`d, as per my answer), *before* accessing the encrypted data.

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to be careful while decrypting data with `CryptoStream`. It is advisable to read it using a `loop`. Calling `Read` only once can lead to truncated results.

```
using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    plainTextBytes = new byte[cleanCipherBytes.Length];

    int read = 0, rem = plainTextBytes.Length;

    do
    {
        read = crypto.Read(plainTextBytes, read, rem);
        rem -= read;
    }
    while (read > 0);
}
```

This took me quite a while to figure out. I hope it saves someone else's time.